# Square a number in NASM assembly without multiplication

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Is it possible to square a number stored in a register (say eax) without doing any multiplication (by using shifts, etc)? I will be squaring a 16-bit number in 32-bit assembly so overflow shouldn't be an issue. I am using NASM x86 assembly to create the program. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What is the reason you want to do this? Do you want to gain performance or is just a challenge for your mind?

Comment: More of a curiosity/challenge. My goal is preserve the contents of the other registers in use. I know that I could push/pop them on/off the stack, but was just wondering if there was a way to do it without the stack.

Comment: Shift & Add to square an arbitrary number is going to require a loop, and that probably means you're going to chew up as many registers or more registers than just doing the multiply.  Also, depending on your hardware, multiply may be a lot faster than discrete shift and add logic.  On Pentium 3 and 4, for example, multiply can complete in 1 clock cycle, same as 1 add.  Later Pentiums backed off of this a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C:

```
int square(int n) {
    int i, r = 0;
    for (i = n; i; i >>= 1, n <<= 1)
        if (i & 1)
            r += n;
    return r;
}
```

I'll leave the NASM to you.

Answer (score 3):

[Shift and Add](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Shift_and_add) is always a good starting point for doing multiplications on computers without involving multiplication instructions.

Precomputing a table is another option that could be suitable for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

A little late answer. Here is the logic:- The square of N can be obtained by adding first N odd numbers.

In C,

```
int sqr(int num){
    int j=1; 
    int sum=0;
    while(num>0){
        sum += j;
        j += 2; 
        num--;
    }
    return sum;
 }
```

but applicable only for integers.